# Finding Common Strings Between Rows in R

Tags: r, string, count, unique

I have a dataframe that has 1 column and 30 rows.In each row is a description that includes 3-4 sentences. I want to be able to find the top most common words shared between all rows. Ie the most unique strings.

For example, "Apple" may be the most common word with 17 occurrences.

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if you could provide an example. But I'll give it a try anyway.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)

tidy_df <- df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%  # this will remove words such as "the", "a", "an"
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```